# Is the passive voice of "he took a photo of me" "I was taken a photo of by him" or "I had my photo taken of by him"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, passive-voice

We have this active sentence "**he took a photo of me**"

If I follow grammar books, its passive will be "**I was taken a photo of by him**" (if the choose the object "**me**" to be the subject)

However, it is more likely that people will say "**I had my photo taken of by him**"

What is the passive voice of "**he took a photo of me**"?

Comment: In the active "He took a photo of me", the direct object is "a photo", and this becomes the subject in the passive to give the unnatural-sounding "A photo of me was taken by him". "I had my photo taken (by him)" is of course more natural, but it is not the true passive counterpart of the original.

Comment: **I had my photo taken by him.** _Of_ is wrong here, because _I_ is the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding a problem like this is to forget about the meaning of the sentence and focus on the grammar.

Grammatically, the verb of the sentence is **took**. The object of this verb is **a photograph**. It answers the question, "What did he take?"

We know that **me** is *not* the object of **took** for two reasons:

1. The person represented by **me** was not taken. **Me** does not answer the question "What was taken?"
2. **me** follows the preposition **of**. It is therefore the object of a preposition, not the object of a verb. ("Take of" is not a phrasal verb.)

All of this points to one conclusion: to transform the original sentence into a corresponding passive sentence, the grammatical subject must be a transformation of **photograph**, *not* **me**. So here is the most obvious passive version:

> A photo of me was taken by him.

Now let's consider the actual meaning of the sentence. As you imagined the situation, your instinct was probably telling you that the object here is **me** because the subject **he** seems to be *doing something* to **me.** And we have a simple verb that captures that relationship: *photograph.* In fact, in the style class that I teach, I would usually advise my students not to write **take a photograph** when it is followed by a phrase like **of me**; rather, I would advise them to trim a few words and use **photograph** as a verb instead of a noun. The result would look like this:

> He photographed me.

Conceptually, this probably describes the relationships that you had in mind when you looked at the original sentence. **me** answers the question, "What did he photograph?"

Now that **me** is the object of the verb **photographed,** it can be transformed into the grammatical subject of the corresponding passive sentence:

> I was photographed by him.

For me at least, this is the most intuitive way of describing the original idea passively.